# Get cell div id using beforecheckchange listener in extjs grid cell editing

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am using `beforeCheckChange` listener for `checkColumn` in extjs grid cell editing.

Once unchecked, I want remove the dirty flag for this cell. So I am trying  to remove `"x-grid-dirty-cell"` Cls, using cell `div` id.

```
Ext.select("ext-gen2654").removeCls('x-grid-dirty-cell');
```

Following is listener

```
listeners: {
    beforecheckchange: me.onCheckcolumnBeforeCheckChange
}

onCheckcolumnBeforeCheckChange: function(comp, rowIndex, checked, eOpts) {  
    Ext.select("ext-gen2654").removeCls('x-grid-dirty-cell');
}
```

How do I get the `div` id for this cell only?

Let me know if we have any alternative to remove dirty record after uncheck.

Edited- display checkbox for alternative records

```
Ext.getCmp('grid').gridColumns[0]=  {
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',                                               
                dataIndex: 'SELECT',
                width: 55,
                stopSelection: true,
                renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
                if(row%2==0){  // i need to display alternative checkbox
                    var cssPrefix = Ext.baseCSSPrefix,
                    cls = cssPrefix + 'grid-checkcolumn';


                        if (this.disabled || value == 'N') {
                            metaData.tdCls += ' ' + this.disabledCls;
                        }
                if (!value) {
                cls += ' ' + cssPrefix + 'grid-checkcolumn-checked';
                }

                    return '<img class="' + cls + '" src="' + Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL + '"/>';
                        }

            }

,

try listener code to remove dirty mark, but no luck

    onCheckcolumnBeforeCheckChange: function(comp, rowIndex, checked, eOpts) {  
        var store=Ext.getCmp('grid').getStore();
        var record= store.getAt(rowIndex);
        if(checked==true){  
        record.dirty= false;
        record.commit();    
        store.commitChanges();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the dirty flags for the whole grid, [use `markDirty` on the grid view](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-cfg-markDirty):

```
viewConfig:{
    markDirty:false
}
```

If you want to remove the dirty flags for the whole column only, just set a tdCls on the column:

```
tdCls:'doNotMarkDirty',
```

and add the following CSS (tested in Classic theme, may be different for other themes):

```
.doNotMarkDirty.x-grid-dirty-cell {
    background-image:none;
}
```

If you want to remove the dirty flags for the whole column, AND have the model ignore any changes made to the column, try [adding a custom `isModified` function to the model definition](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-isModified):

```
isModified:function(dataIndex) {
      if(dataIndex=="myDataIndex") return false;
      me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

If you want to let a record know that it is no longer dirty, check out [`record.commit()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-commit).

Comment: Thanks for details. basically I dont want to disable mark dirty for this column. I am using checkcolumn to display checkbox. when I checked checobox it shows dirty mark, but when I uncheck, it still display dirty mark. so when I am trying to manually remove dirty mark when I uncheck it.

Comment: Then you have an issue with your input data. Please try whether marking your model's field as `type:'boolean'` and/or adding `defaultValue:false` helps.

Comment: The dirty flag is shown whenever the original value is different from the current value of the record field. Go figure.

Comment: I think if modified any field then it shows dirty flag. if we reset it original value, still it shows dirty flag

Comment: Sorry, but what you think doesn't matter, what matters is the original ExtJS code, which states clearly: `if (me.markDirty && record.dirty && record.isModified(column.dataIndex)) {` (view/Table.js:1569). [I have made a fiddle for you, if you don't believe the code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17d4).

Comment: Thanks for sample. I tried same with my code but no luck. I am using 4.2 version. is version issue?

Comment: No it isn't. You can check by switching the version in the fiddle. Make a fiddle exhibiting the problem, it's hard to say what the problem is without seeing your code.

Comment: I have change same fiddle with 'Ext JS 4.2.1.883 Neptune'. it shows blank. is any thing more need to change